# Run a IF statement inside a for loop with ssh

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ssh

I have two pieces of code that work independently, but not together. I need to put the if statement inside the <Command_To_Be_Ran>. Any ideas to how i can get this to work?

```
for i in t{1..2}; do
  ssh -qex -t $i 'echo <Sudo_Password> | sudo -S <Command_To_Be_Ran>'
done
```

and

```
if (( $(grep -o "fips=1" /etc/default/grub | wc -l) > 1 )); then 
    sed -i 's/ fips=1//' /etc/default/grub
fi
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3872762/1745001

Comment: FYI it should be possible to simplify the conditional to `if grep -q "fips=1" /etc/default/grub`, which uses the grep exit status instead of counting matched lines with `wc`

Answer (score 0):

I think now it will work :D

```
for i in t{1..2}; do    
  ssh -qex -t $i "echo <Sudo_Password> | sudo -S bash -c '\
    if (( $(grep -o 'fips=1' /etc/default/grub | wc -l) > 1 )); \
      then sed -i 's/ fips=1//' /etc/default/grub ;\
    fi'"
done
```

should work, the line breaks can be replaced with `;` and `bash -c` and the double quotes (`"`) enable you to run a command like from within a shell.

If you have zsh installed (or even in some versions of bash) you could probably use `eval` instead of `bash -c`

Comment: Trying to get this to work but there is a single quote right before the echo on the sudo password. This makes it get ingested incorrectly stopping at the first single quote at the fips=1... atleast i believe. Testing now.

Comment: now it should work

Comment: You should create a local script and feed it to you ssh session, it will be much easier to execute and write. As far as the bash goes you can use the `--` trick.

Comment: i would agree, but i assume he wants to run the command on multiple systems, hence the for loop

Comment: I think Ed Morton is right, that's probably a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3872762/1745001